# Pyscreenshot не работает с PyQt5(Pyinstaller)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, screenshots

Когда я запускаю приложение с IDE, оно работает идеально, но когда я запускаю собранное PyInstaller'ом приложние, pyscreenshot.grab работает как MainWindow.show(). Я пробовал 3 разных бэкенда(PyQt5; PIL; default) и ни один не работает. Если вы не поняли меня, можете посмотреть [видео](https://youtu.be/qaGZ3GS-9wI)

Если я закрываю основное окно, появляется ошибка:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "threading.py", line 870, in run
  File "main1.py", line 96, in main
  File "lib\site-packages\pyscreenshot\__init__.py", line 31, in grab
  File "lib\site-packages\pyscreenshot\loader.py", line 145, in backend_grab
  File "lib\site-packages\pyscreenshot\loader.py", line 136, in force
  File "lib\site-packages\pyscreenshot\childproc.py", line 39, in childprocess_grab
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pyscreenshotmrgm1pkk\\screenshot.png'
```

P.S. Использую dev версию PyInstaller, т.к. мне нужна поддержка TensorFlow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использование `PIL.ImageGrab.grab()` вместо `pyscreenshot.grab()` решило проблему